# How to pass multiple parameters with Special Characters using URL access in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameter-passing, url-parameters

I am trying to use SSRS URL access to send parameters to a SSRS report.

The most recommended approach online was to use following syntax:

**http://Server1/ReportServer?http://server1/sites/Test/Reports/YearlyTrend.rdl&rs:command=render&parameter1=Value1&parameter2=value2**

The above works except in cases where parameter values contains special characters for example:

one of my parameters (pOrganization) is:

**[Organization].[Hierarchy - Department].[Organization].&[Corporate]&[Support]&[Vancouver]**

This does not work because it contains many special characters.

I tried to use HTML encoding for **& and [**  using **%26 and %5B** but it still doesn't work.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone can help me solve this mystery, or correct my syntax. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check [this](http://capstonebi.blogspot.com.co/2010/04/url-encoding-in-reporting-services.html)? Also you can pass only the value and in SSRS produce the proper dimension member. `"[myDim].[myAttr].[" + Parameters!parameter.Value + "]"`

Comment: @alejandrozuleta: Thank you so much. That works like a charm. This fixed my problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @alejandroZuleta, I was able to fix this issue by using UrlEncode function available within .Net library.

Step by Step details can be found here: http://capstonebi.blogspot.com.co/2010/04/url-encoding-in-reporting-services.html